# ¿Cómo actualizar dos campos en php update?

Tags: php, bootstrap, mysqli

Hola chicos estoy haciendo un formulario que a través de una botón de editar actualice los campos seleccionados, me recoge el dato en el echo, pero no me lo actualiza ni en el formulario ni en la bbdd que puedo estar haciendo mal ? gracias de antemano.
Las tablas son las correctas una es un int, y el otro un varchar de 13, pero no veo la forma.

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    //UPDATE detalles SET det_cantidad = '5' WHERE detalles.det_id = 235; query para actualizar, compruebo primero que funciona correctamente en phpmyadmin
    $sql_actualizar = "UPDATE detalles SET det_cantidad = $_POST[det_cantidad],det_libro = '$_POST[det_libro]' WHERE det_id = $_GET[linea]";
    echo $sql_actualizar;
    $query_run = mysqli_query($link,$sql_actualizar);

}
```

[image: Imagen 1]
[image: Imagen 2]

[image: imagen 3]

Comment: Hola Quizá se porque "det_libro" lo estas enviando como tipo String y en la BD lo tengas como tipo INT.

Answer (score 0):

Hola como indiqué antes los campos son varchar en sus correspondientes tablas con su clave primaria y con su clave foranea en ambas tablas.
[image: imagen1]
[image: imagen2]